# android studio sdk not installing after unzipping and running

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-studio-2.3

i downloaded [older android studio version 2.3.2](https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.3.2.0/android-studio-ide-162.3934792-windows32.zip) and after running android studio there is error saying software development kit not available.

how to solve sdk error can you help as i tried but can't find the solution. And, so the studio is not running.